# How to calculate $i^i$

Tags: complex-numbers

I've been struggling with this problem, actually I was doing a program in python and did

`1j ** 1j`(complex numbers) (In python `a**b` = $a^b$ )

and found out the answer to be a real number with value $0.2079$, How to calculate this value of $i^i$?

Comment: not really a duplicate of the first question-- this is a more specific question and the asker of the first seems to have less background. I also think it's not a duplicate of the second although the author would benefit from reading the second.

Comment: Why these would not be duplicates escapes me, I am afraid. The fascinating thing about these "$z^w$, $z$ and $w$ complex" questions is their repetition (hence, their is a demand) and the repetition of unsatisfying answers (from which one can deduce that the subject is horribly taught).

Comment: @Integrator Right, let me teach then: *There is no such thing as a function $z\mapsto z^w$ defined unambiguously (e.g. continuously, say) when $w$ is complex, not real integer*. (Note that the Edit to your answer, posted after my comment above which may have caused the trouble, is odd since it alternates between the postmodern view that $z^w$ is a *set* and some old-fashioned identities where $z^w$ is indeed one complex number.)

Comment: @Integrator Really? Then we can begin by this: *what is $i^i$, according to you?* A number, a set, a tiger, or a helicopter?

Comment: @Integrator Maybe this is a language problem but I understand next to nothing to your comment. "I asked robjohn" You asked robjohn what? And robjohn said what? And why should robjohn be involved in this? "I don't really understand what that statement really means" My last comment mainly contains, not a statement but, a question: **what is $i^i$?** The question seems simple enough, what is there to "understand" in it? If you cannot answer it, this is another matter.

Comment: ((Three comments by @Integrator now deleted. I don't know what is happening here.))

Comment: @Integrator Sorry but, if you delete your comments once I answered them, where are we going? All this begins to look awfully like an evasion tactics (and I am not much interested in this game).

Comment: @Integrator No.

Comment: ((Two other comments by @Integrator now deleted.))

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> First you need to realize that this is a multi-valued function.

---

$$i=0+i$$
$$i=\cos\left(\frac{(4k+1)\pi}{2}\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{(4k+1)\pi}{2}\right)$$
$k\in \mathbb Z$,
Using Euler's formula
[$$e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_formula)

$$i=e^{\large{i(4k+1)\pi}/{2}}$$

Now

$$\begin{align}i^i&=\left(e^{\large {i(4k+1)\pi}/{2}}\right)^i\\
&=e^{\large{i\times i(4k+1)\pi}/{2}}\\
&=e^{\large{-(4k+1)\pi}/{2}}\\
\end{align}$$

Depending on the branch cut (part of $\mathbb{C}$ excluded) and branch of log (what value $\log(z_0)$ has for some $z_0$ not in the branch cut), there is a $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ so that $i^i=e^{-(4k+1)\pi/2}$. Using the most standard branch cut, $i^i=e^{-\pi/2}$

---

And python didn't seem to care about that and returned

> $$i^i=e^{\large{-\pi}/{2}}\approx 0.2078795$$

Comment: Remember that $i$ also equals $e^{5i\pi/2}$, which gives a different answer.

Comment: @Arthur So how can we say that it is `0.2079` only

Comment: Here's a related one on MO: http://mathoverflow.net/a/94833/13042

Comment: To expand on what @Arthur said, this depends on what the choice of argument you use. This is similar to the complex logarithm.

Comment: Considering Euler's formula $e^{i\pi} + 1 = 0$ I think Integrator's **principal** answer was correct. I left an answer, which describes how Euler's **principal** formula is used.

Comment: @Integrator So is this the answer or shall I have to go through the choice of argument thing to find the correct answer?

Comment: @Integrator, deserves downvotes for this new answer. Most questions asked depend on the interval of **principal** interval. For sine, it is $[-2\pi, 2\pi]$, similar to that.

Comment: @PruthviRaj, I dont think this is correct. Most answers including **wolframalpha** take the principal values.

Answer (score 4):

$e^{i\pi} = -1$

$i = \sqrt{e^{i\pi}}$

$i^i = e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}}$

I just wanted to point out the derivation!

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: But I used Euler's formula. $e^{i\pi} + 1 = 0$ then I derived the rest.

Comment: This is not that bad, but I can equally ask, since $e^{i3\pi} = -1$, can you come up with a more general formula for $i^i$, or complex power in general?